# ST_Intersects PostGIS returns empty table

Tags: postgis, postgresql

[Here is a link to download the two layers I am working with](https://github.com/epurpur/TestParcels) (as geopackages).

I have two tables in a PostgreSQL database, 'WataugaResidential' and 'zone1shape'. I'm trying to use ST_Intersects function from PostGIS to see where they overlap. Using QGIS, if I run the Vector > Research Tools > Select by Location I get the following result:

[image]

Trying to do the same in PostgreSQL, I get an empty table returned as my result. Here is the SQL code I'm using:

```
SELECT res.*
FROM public."WataugaResidential" as res, public."zone1shape" as z1
WHERE ST_Intersects(res.geom, z1.geom);
```

Pretty simple stuff. But my result is an empty table. All the columns are there, but no data. Result:

[image]

Why is nothing returned?

Comment: What SRIDs were used to load the two tables?  If they're not the same, then the comparison operators always return False.

Comment: This is it.  The SRID is different.  Such a simple detail to overlook.